# autotools: Can I stop make dist from compiling everything in order to generate the tar.gz?

Tags: autotools

I have a large project with autotools that can be built as an rpm.  The rpm build works by running the make dist target in order to generate a .tar.gz file which is then passed to rpmbuild with the -ta flag to create the rpm.

The result of this is that compilation happens twice, once for make dist and again during the rpm build.  It takes forever.  Is there a way I can get make dist to tar everything without compiling it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`make dist` does not compile everything; however, `make distcheck` does. This is because it wants to run the test suite, which is all the way at the end of the dependency chain.

If you don't want to run everything, then don't, and use `make dist` rather than `make distcheck`...

Answer (score 1):

I do this also.  The `make dist` target *should* just build the tarball.  There's something wrong with your `make dist` rules, or your build steps if it really does make everything.  Doing:

```
configure...
make dist
```

Should not trigger anything but the tarball build.